# How can I use the value of a variable from one class in another in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am fairly new to Objective-C and have been doing some iPhone programming.

Is it possible to look up the value of a variable in a different class?

Basically what I am doing is running a function that exists in my application delegate from a view controller, but the application delegate needs to use a variable stored in the view controller from which the application delegate function was called. Does it make sense?

Comment: That sounds like a convoluted design. If you can explain more about what the variable does and why the app delegate needs it, you might get much better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass the variable into the function which needs it. Or you can make a getter for it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by simply passing the variable to the app delegate and doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you need to expose that variable as a property.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton and store your data and have it available all over the place.